# Change Apache root directory

Tags: apache, osx-yosemite

I am having problems changing the root directory in Apache 2.4.9 on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.2.  I am using this tutorial: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/forbidden-403-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-username-on-this-server/

When I navigate to http://localhost/~Owner/ , I get 404 Not found.

The conf file is in the apache2/user folder. Here is the [httpd](http://pastie.org/private/kyvapmflkd1srjyfacifsw) file, my [conf](http://pastie.org/private/ifn5ao7i2fpp1o0ruw2ukg) file, and the [httpd-user](http://pastie.org/private/vawghravkkvasmegqehgta) .

Please be as explicit as you be with your answer; as I learn better examining code, watching a video somebody doing **live coding and testing**.

Comment: what about `http://localhost`

Comment: @Simo http://localhost works; but, it points to the root directory /Library/Web.../Document.  I want to another directory.

Comment: Open the httpd.conf file and change `ServerRoot "/My/Path"` and restart appache

Comment: @Simo it did not work

Comment: what is the name of your default directory ?

Comment: @Simo The "name" of the default directory is DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"

I tried to change this "link" to where I want; but it did not work ether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply download and installed [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/).  Then I change the root directory.